# How to assign vars to threads for status updates

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I am building software in a c# console app

My code for creating a thread and assigning it to a function:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => util.Menu());
```

What I want to be able to do is have a menu that displays threads current status for example:

```
--THREAD 1--
Status: BUSY

--THREAD 2--
Status: IDLE
```

etc...

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your code creates `Task`s, not threads. Maybe you want to display a menu with each tasks's [`Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status)?

Answer (score 1):

Now it is recommended to use `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` ([TaskFactory.StartNew Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.8)), however as both are returning `Task` so it makes no difference to my answer.

whichever you choose will return a task that you can add these tasks to a list and then you can get status of any of them:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => util.Menu));
```

and then you can get the status of them:

```
var status = tasks.Select((t, i) => new { Id = i + 1, t.Status});
```

and:

```
foreach(var item in status)
    Console.WriteLine($"--Task {item.Id}--\r\nStatus: {item.Status}");
```